# Array is not updating swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I trying to update the array when the user change the input.

Here is the `viewModel`

```
struct  Person: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var age : String
}

class PersonViewModel : ObservableObject{
  
    @Published var PersonArray = [Person]()
    
    func emptyPersonArray() {
        self.PersonArray.append(Person(name: "", age: ""))
    }
   
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var personViewModel = PersonViewModel()
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                personViewModel.emptyPersonArray()
            }) {
                HStack {
                        Text("Add")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .bold()
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .frame(width: 150.72, height: 40)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color(red: 0.463, green: 0.483, blue: 1.034), lineWidth: 2))
            
            
        List{
            ForEach(personViewModel.PersonArray) {person in
                PersonView(person: person,name: person.name, age: person.age)
            }.padding(.leading, -150)
        }
            Button(action: {
                for person in personViewModel.PersonArray{
                    print("Person Name: \(person.name)") 
                    print("Person Age: \(person.age)")
                }
            }) {
                HStack {
                        Text("Show data")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .bold()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is `PersonView`:

```
struct PersonView: View {
    @State var person: Person
    @State var name = ""
    @State var age = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 650, height: 180)
            
            VStack (alignment: .center) {
               
                  
                        Text("Person")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                          
                  
                VStack{
                Text("Enter Name:")
                    TextField("", text: $name)
                        .onChange(of: name, perform: { newValue in
                            person.name = newValue
                        })
                        .frame(width: 289, height: 40.0)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.black))
                        
                Text("Enter Age:")
                    TextField("", text: $age).padding()
                        .onChange(of: age, perform: { newValue in
                            person.age = newValue
                        })
                        .frame(width: 289, height: 40.0)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.black))
                }   .padding(.leading)
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I tried to print it shows empty and did not update:
[image]

**The problem have be solved**
by changing the `@State` to `@Binding` in `PersonView`

```
struct PersonView: View {
    @Binding var person: Person

    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 650, height: 180)
            
            VStack (alignment: .center) {
               
                  
                        Text("Person")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                          
                  
                VStack{
                Text("Enter Name:")
                    TextField("", text: $person.name)
                        .onChange(of: person.name, perform: { newValue in
                            person.name = newValue
                        })
                        .frame(width: 289, height: 40.0)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.black))
                        
                Text("Enter Age:")
                    TextField("", text: $person.age).padding()
                        .onChange(of: person.age, perform: { newValue in
                            person.age = newValue
                        })
                        .frame(width: 289, height: 40.0)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color.black))
                }   .padding(.leading)
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your PersonView you need to use `@Binding` and not `@State` for the Person object and I don't see why you need the other two `@State` properties at all.

Comment: You must either use `@StateObject` or inject your `viewModel` if you use `@ObservedObject`. For more information, see the linked duplicate targets.